# How to get value for objective function in Gekko

Tags: python, gekko

I have a working program in Gekko that outputs

```
EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is   -17.8543906759043     

---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   0.158899999994901      sec
 Objective      :   -17.8543906759043     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

All I want to do is save the value for the objective function. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the objective function with:

```
m.options.OBJFCNVAL
```

There is additional documentation on the [objective function value](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/global.html?highlight=objfcnval#objfcnval), [solver iterations](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/global.html?highlight=objfcnval#iterations), [solve time](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/global.html?highlight=objfcnval#solvetime), [solver status](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/global.html?highlight=objfcnval#solvestatus), and other parameters.